# predicting an event from a time series

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

Heads up: I am a complete newbie to machine learning and time series, but I know a bit of python and data analysis. The following question is vaguely phrased because I am looking for advices on what tools (packages, techniques...) may be most useful to my goal.

I have a time series consisting of a number of daily observations for a large data set of (presumably independent) entities. Sometimes an event (let's call it a catastrophic event) happens to an entity, and this means we cannot make an observation for a certain number of days.

I have reason to suspect that one may be able to predict the catastrophic event based on the behavior of the time series right before it. This prediction will not be particularly accurate, but at least it should improve our priors in a Bayesian sense: P(event|certain behavior of time series)>P(event).

Googling online for time series in python, all I can find are articles teaching you how to predict future values in a time series, which is not my case. I also found articles describing how to infer the effect of certain events on future values of a time series - but that's the opposite causality than the one I need.

So, what are the theoretical keywords/techniques I should look up, and what kind of Pythonic stuff should I look into? Any advice is strongly appreciated!

Comment: I'm working on something similar, it's time series of action potential, also you can find the Data-set  _small size_ [Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360517/neural-network-isnt-working-perfectly-same-class-always-as-output) I hope you can get the main idea because the code itself needs some improvments